# Problem with creating a Procedure which should filter data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a procedure which filters data and insert it to a table.

I have 4 tables:  (the keys are the id's)

**table1:**
    id1
    parameter1
    parameter2
    parameter3

**table2:**
    id1
    id2

**table3:**
    id2
    id3
    value1
    value2
    value3

**table4:**
    id2
    id3
    value1
    value2
    value3

I need to create a procedure which inserts to **table 4**  the values from **table 3**: value1, value2, value3, only if they are smaller than or equal to the parameters from **table 1** (parameter1, parameter2, parameter3)

I've tried the next thing:

```
    insert into table4 ( 
        ,Id2  
        ,Id3  
        ,value1  
        ,value2  
        ,value3  
        )
    select  
        ,Id2  
        ,Id3  
        ,value1  
        ,value2  
        ,value3  

    FROM table1   
         LEFT JOIN table2  ON table1.id1 = table2.id1  
         LEFT JOIN table3  ON table2.id2 = table3.id3  
    WHERE       table3.value1 <= table1.parameter1   
            and table3.value2 <= table1.parameter2  
            and table3.value3 <= table1.parameter3
```

But each run, 3 new rows are inserted to table4 with different values and wrong values (they are bigger than the parameters).

What am I doing wrong? Should I create the procedure with IF statement instead? How to make it right?

I've added an example.
As you can see, the new table: table 4, has only 2 rows, because the value of *'value 2'* in **table3** (value 2= 12) is greater than *'parameter2'* (parameter2= 11) (from **table 1**)

table1:

```
 Id1 | Parameter1 |  Parameter2 | Parameter3 |  
=====+============+=============+============+
 1   |      1     |      2      |      3     |  
 2   |      10    |   ** 11 **  |      12    |   
 3   |      10    |      15     |      16    |
```

table2:

```
 Id1 | Id2 |  
=====+=====+
 1   |  4  |  
 2   |  5  |   
 3   |  6  |
```

table3:

```
 Id2 | Id3 |  Value1| Value2| Value3|  
=====+=====+========+=======+=======+
 4   |  7  |    1   |   2   |   3   |  
 5   |  8  |    10  |** 12**|   12  |   
 6   |  9  |    1   |   2   |   3   |
```

The new table (table 4) should be:
table4:

```
 Id2 | Id3 |  Value1| Value2| Value3|  
=====+=====+========+=======+=======+
 4   |  7  |    1   |   2   |   3   |  
 6   |  9  |    1   |   2   |   3   |
```

Comment: Well the first thing, being new and all that, is to tag the correct RDBMS - you have tagged 2, MySQL and SQL Server - which should it be?

Comment: The second thing is, show some sample data and expected results (as formatted text), so we can see visually what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include [proper sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and desired results.

Comment: Please do not post images instead of sample data. I've given you a link in my previous comment, please read it and follow it's instructions.

Comment: table3.id3 - does not exist is this a typo and should be id2 or is the table definition wrong? BTW changing to id2 does not populate table4..AND you are not populating id1 or id2 in table4.

Comment: You mostly on the right track. Try changing `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` and (as per @P.Salmon) sort out your id columns.

Comment: table 3 and table4 should have Id2 and Id3, I've fixed it. Also populating id2 and id3 in table 4. 
@P.Salmon

Comment: I tried to change from LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN, but I still get the same results (wrong results and 3 rows inserted to table 4, instead of 1 row) @Alex

Comment: Your query now produces the desired result..if you change table2.id2 = table3.id3  to table2.id2 = table3.id2

Answer (score 2):

If you use table3 as the table you select from, you can use joins with the other tables as filters when inserting. Try this (for SQL Server):

```
INSERT INTO table4 (
    id2
    ,id3
    ,value1
    ,value2
    ,value3
    )
SELECT
    t3.id2
    ,t3.id3
    ,t3.value1
    ,t3.value2
    ,t3.value3
FROM table3 t3
JOIN table2 t2 on t3.id2 = t2.id2
JOIN table1 t1 on t2.id1 = t1.id
    and t3.value1 <= t1.parameter1
    and t3.value2 <= t1.parameter2
    and t3.value3 <= t1.parameter3
```